# Why is $\lim_{x \to 0^+}(e^{\sin x\, \cdot\, \ln x})$ equal to $e^{\lim_{x \to 0^+}(\sin x\, \cdot\, \ln x)}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Can someone give me a simple explanation of why this works (and what it's called)?

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}(e^{\sin x\, \cdot\, \ln x}) = e^{\lim_{x \to 0^+}(\sin x\, \cdot\, \ln x)}$$

I can't find an explanation anywhere online...

Comment: Its called continuity of the exponential function (specifically right continuity at 0)

Comment: let $f(x) = e^x$ and $g(x) = \sin x \cdot \ln x$. Can you write your limit expression in terms of $f$ and $g$ ?

Comment: It'll be the limit of f(g(x)), right?

Comment: yes so you seem to have  $$\lim\limits_{x\to c} f(g(x)) = f(\lim\limits_{x\to c} g(x)) $$

Comment: watch [this short video on khan academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-limits-new/ab-1-5a/v/limits-of-composite-functions#:~:text=Suppose%20we%20are%20looking%20for,%3Da%2C%20under%20two%20conditions.) and get back if you have questions

Comment: because e is a constant value. This can be done for any constant value. What changes is on exponent.

Answer (score 1):

Here the function $e^x$ is a continuous function over the range of $\ln x \cdot \sin x$ (which is just $\mathbb{R}$). By definition of continuity, we know that as $x \to k$, $e^x \to e^k$. So in particular, as $\ln x \cdot \sin x \to L = \lim_{x \to 0^+} \ln x \cdot \sin x$ (supposing this limit existed), it would have to follow that $e^{\ln x \cdot \sin x} \to e^L$.

It's important to note that in general, when you are evaluating the limit of $f(g(x))$ as $x \to k$, you need $f(x)$ to be continuous over the range of $g(x)$, or at least in a neighborhood of $L = \lim_{x \to k} g(x)$ (again, supposing it existed) to conclude that $f(L) = \lim_{x \to k} f(g(x))$. It does not suffice to have $f$ continuous in a region around $k$. For example, if instead the problem were to evaluate $\lim_{x \to 2} f(\sin(x))$
where $f(x)$ was continuous at $2$ but not around $\sin(2)$, you could not conclude that
$$f\left(\lim_{x \to 2} \sin x\right) = \lim_{x \to 2} f(\sin x)$$